# How to set mask size when apply inverse-FFT to the power spectrum of HAADF-STEM image?

Tags: computational-physics, fourier-transform, software, microscopy, image-processing

[image: enter image descriptioenter image description heren here]

[image]

Hello everyone, I want to characterize dislocation in my FIB sample using Titan electron transmission microscopy and I want to use FFT filter to process my HAADF-STEM image with DigitalMicrograph (GMS3) software. I found that inverse FFT images are different based on different mask size I chose. For example, in the above figure, I set mask to same two spot ((100)plane) in frequence domin, you can see that inverse FFT image showed different disloaction density, bigger mask size corresponds to more edge dislocation and more distorted lattice, samller mask size corresponds to less edge dislocation and more flat lattice. I'm confused now, how to choose the correct mask size so that inverse FFT image can  reveal real situation of my STEM sample?

Answer (score 1):

Remember what the FFT shows you and apply the mask in that manner.
I.e. low frequency is your center band and higher frequencies are the ones around.

If you apply a small mask around one of your "diffraction" spots (really it is the FFT, a mathematical operation, not the real life diffraction pattern), you will see what contributed to that spot. If you go for a larger mask, you will include more signal from other spots in the FFT.

So the answer is not straight forward to answer, there is no "real answer", but it is dependent on the sample and what you aim for.